# search bar,restaurant and pub from facebook graph explorer api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

search bar,restaurant and pub from facebook graph explorer api then I am getting bar plus some other categories where the bar,restaurant and pub are found in name parameter also.
please tell me the query where I just get  bar,restaurant and pub in category instead of other paramter.below I link use for search:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/search?type=place&q=restaurant/bar&center=46.187884100000000000,-123.831253399999980000&distance=2000&access_token={access_token}

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to search by single page categories

Comment: then tell me the another way to get only bar places

Comment: What part of "it's not possible" didn't you understand? You could fitler the results in your application, that's all.

Comment: k fine. but my question is that the text which I am specifying (for eg; bar or pub), this text should be search only within the category parameter and not in other parameters. However, as of now it is searching the specified text in all the parameters. I am showing below example:

Comment: "category": "Bar",
         "category_list": [ { "name": "Restaurant"},
            {"name": "Bar"
            }
         ],
                 "name": "Labor Temple Diner & Bar",
               },
      {
         "category": "Local business",
         "category_list": [ {
               "name": "Food & Restaurant"
            }
         ],
      
         "name": "Todd's Worker Bar ",
          } Here bar is searching in category or name parameter

Comment: You ***cannot*** restrict the search to only some fields.